# Как экспортировать огромное количество строк из dataTable primefaces?

Tags: java, primefaces

Помогите разобраться. По работе пришлось заюзать `dataExporter` из `org.primefaces 5.3` используя библиотеку`poi`. По идеи все должно работать просто и отлично, но на практике не все просто. У меня в `dataTable` загружается пару сотен тысяч строк. И это вызывает проблемы. На самой таблице я использую пагинацию и ленивый список. На страницу загружается по 50 строк, и при нажатии на новую страницу я загружаю новые 50 строк только уже с 50й строки и до сотой. ну и тд. Все работает отлично. Но при экспорте, `dataExporter` вызывает метод, который используется `dataTable'ом` для загрузки данных, но передает ему параметры для загрузке 0 - это с какой строки грузить и максимальное значение таблицы-это сколько строк надо грузить. А максимальное значение равно сотням тысяч строк. Выходит моим селектом вытаскивается куча строк и пихается в лист, чтобы экспортнуть в ексель. А так как данных дофига сервер падает с переполнением памяти. Так вот вопрос - как можно экспортировать данные из `dataTable primefaces` в ексель, по частям а не разом?

Comment: Прямо на сервере формируйте xls на лету через servlet, на который ведёт ссылка download. Там то уж совсем просто подобрать подходящий вариант для загрузки данных.

Comment: уже думаю об этом, но вопрос задал чтоб наверняка убедиться. Просто так не удобно немного. сформирую на сервере отчет и выплюну ссылку? может можно как то прикрутить filechooser како нить? чтоб юзер нажал загрузить и указал куда?

Comment: На лету - это когда отчета ещё никакого нет, но есть ссылка. Пользователь щёлкает по ней. Теперь на сервере формируется отчёт и по мере формирования тут же выгружается пользователю. Безо всяких временно/постоянных файлов. Формирование идёт в output stream servlet-а. На своей стороне пользователь может указывать куда сохранить файл или найти его в стандартной папке для загрузок обычным способом.